# Using Checkbox in ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, checkbox, view

I'm trying to make Todo app. I want to make checkbox next to task, so when you select it, the task is set to done. The problem is, I can't really know how to change value of my BooleanField in Task Model. There are plenty of posts like this, but they are usually using functions inside views.py or use forms, but I can't relate do my form in ListView.

views.py

```
class TodolistView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Todolist
template_name = 'todolist.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Todolist.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    todolist_objects = Todolist.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'todolist.html', {'todolist_objects': todolist_objects})
```

todolist.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <p><a href="{% url 'todolist_create' %}">Add new task</a></p>

    {% for todo in todolist_objects %}
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <li> {{ todo }} <a href="{% url 'todolist_detail' todo.pk %}">see details</a></l>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just to calrify, it should be saved immediately after you clicked the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, that's my plan.